# How to change color of material ui v4 Button with image and text

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying change the foreground color of a material ui v4 button that has a svg image and text. The text changes color alright, however not the image. I have dropped in the browser debugger and tried setting the color css manually on the button, it doesn't even work there, do I need to use a different attribute besides color? I have to use v4 since the rest of the code base is that.

```
import image from "Images/icons/icon.svg";
import clsx from "clsx";
import {Button, makeStyles, Typography} from "@material-ui/core";

const styles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    button: {
        color: "black",
        "&:hover": {
            color: "red",
            "& $icon": {
                color: "red",
            }
        },
    },
    icon: () => ({
        color: "black",
    }),
    layout: {
        textTransform: 'none',
        color: "inherit",
    },
}));

const classes = styles(props);

return (
<>
  <Button
      color="inherit"
      className={clsx(classes.button)}
      onClick={handleClick}
      startIcon={
      <img className={clsx(classes.icon)} src={image} />}
  >
      <Typography className={clsx(classes.layout)}>
          Share
      </Typography>
  </Button>
<>
);
```

If I add a second image in a different color and change the Button component to add these fields it works, however it seems like a very hacky solution, any idea how to do this in css?

```
  <Button
      color="inherit"
      className={clsx(classes.shareButton)}
      onClick={handleClick}
      onMouseEnter={(e: any) => {
          e.currentTarget.children[0].children[0].children[0].src = imageHover
      }}
      onMouseLeave={(e: any) => {
          e.currentTarget.children[0].children[0].children[0].src = image
      }}
      startIcon={
      <img
          className={clsx(classes.icon)}
          src={image}
      />}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<img>` tag, use the raw SVG instead. This allow you to specify `fill="currentColor"` property, which inherits from font color of the parent. Example below:

```css
button:hover {
  color: red;
}
svg {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    height="24"
    viewBox="0 96 960 960"
    width="24"
  >
    <path
      d="M378 810 154 586l43-43 181 181 384-384 43 43-427 427Z"
      fill="currentColor"
    /></svg
  >Hello World
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your main goal is to set `fill="currentColor"` to your svg image.
Here's an example.

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import SvgIcon from '@material-ui/core/SvgIcon';

// Try to build your Icon as SvgIcon end edit your svg to have the property fill="currentColor" and then pass your color to the component.
function HomeIcon(props) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon {...props}>
      <path d="M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12 3 2 12h3v8z" fill="currentColor" />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    "&:hover": {
      color: "red",
    },
  },
}));

return (
  <Button
      className={classes.button}
      onClick={handleClick}
      startIcon={<HomeIcon />}
  >
       Share
  </Button>
```